# Equivalent of node.js Buffer from Array in Python

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to migrate a node.js script to a python script. I only have one issue.

The example below is an array which converted into a buffer in Node;

```
client.write(new Buffer(commandBytes), function() { ...
```

I'm not too sure how to do this in python, this is what I got so far;

```
client.sendall(buffer(commandBytes))
```

but this throws a TypeError: buffer object expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer` requires the object being passed to it to be of a certain type (ie.: a buffer object).

This includes string, unicode, bytearray, mmap.mmap or array.array. Are you feeding it a list?

Comment: yep that was the issue, was using a list instead of an array